# using array in SQLReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, arrays

in the following code , Im trying to assign reader(r33) into array so i can use the values of this array in the next sql command. can you help me doing this ?

```
//connection
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=BookStoreDataBase1;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;");
c.Open();
//first statment
string raf = string.Format("Select Id  from [Order] WHERE customerID={0}", k);
SqlCommand comm1 = new SqlCommand(raf, c);
SqlDataReader r33 = comm1.ExecuteReader();
r33.Read();
int [] k2 = r3.GetInt32(0);
r33.Close();

//second statment
string raf4 = string.Format("Select *  from orderDetails WHERE orderId={0}", k2);
SqlCommand comm14 = new SqlCommand(raf4, c);
SqlDataReader r333 = comm14.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Instead of array you can use SQL DataAdapter then you have to assign value in DataSet. So you have to used DataSet value for any logic...

Comment: can you edit the code with DataAdapter ?

Comment: If your goal is to get `OrderDetails` you can combine two queries (`JOIN`).

Comment: no my goal is the second statement only. i don't want to use join.

Comment: @ToOt - Will first query i.e. `Select Id  from [Order] WHERE customerID={0}` will return single `Id` or multiple?

Comment: @ToOt - Yes means? Single or Multiple?

Comment: @RahulSingh  Multiple rows

Comment: Do you absolutely need the IDs for something else, or wouldn't `"Select *  from orderDetails WHERE orderId IN (Select Id  from [Order] WHERE customerID=@CustomerID)"` be a better choice of sql statement? Btw. please use parameterized queries or you might meet [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) sooner than you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not very sure what you asked, but as far as I understood, you first query will return multiple rows containing different IDs and you want to use them in second command. Basic way of doing it would be :

```
string IDs = "(";
while (r33.read())
{
    IDs += r33.GetString(0) + ",";
}
IDs += ")"
IDs = IDs.Replace(",)",")");
```

and then use IN keyword for multiple IDs you got

```
string raf4 = string.Format("Select *  from orderDetails WHERE orderId IN {0}", IDs);
```

Comment: and how can use it in the last sql query ?

Comment: what should i type inside yourlenght ?

Comment: wait I'll rewrite the answer properly